# Where is the Dockerfile used with Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, microservices

I'm a junior Java developer and I'm learning about Docker. At the job we'are developing microservices with Spring Boot using Dockerfile and in the Dockerfile I see there is configuration for Tomcat. And I want to ask you where is this Dockerfile used? At the deploying? We're using Jenkins pipeline to deploy on Openshift. Is this Dockerfile used when the app is deployed on Openshift? Thank you!

Comment: Does https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/ or https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/ help?

Comment: @gaby, In your case Dockerfile will be used to build docker Image container for `Openshift`, there may be changes of the docker-compose usage also, as you said the server configurations are mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a Dockerfile.

For example, depending on how you've set up your project, then Maven/Gradle would include one for you, or the project could use [Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib)